# Connect Cognito from Lambda for Client Credentials Grant

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cognito

How will I be able to connect **Cognito** using python **boto3** (client credentials grant) to get the access_token as in the postman tool? Which method should use from the **boto3** library?

[Postman tool request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QObT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Client Credentials flow is one of the OAuth flows Cognito supports. The standard AWS SDK's like Boto3, do not have any methods that interact with these OAuth endpoints.

Boto3 can make standard API calls to the Cognito service like initiate_auth for authentication but not these endpoints.

As a result, you would simply use any HTTP client, like the requests library, to make a request to your Token endpoint to obtain token an Access token.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html